# free-jqgrid how to apply filter to main and subgrid(s)

Tags: filtering, free-jqgrid, subgrid

I am using free-jqgrid 4.13.1. In my grid, I have subgrids under each row so I have a nested rows sort of scenario. However, the filters for the top of the grid only apply to the main grid and ignore the subgrids. How can I make the filter at the top of the grid apply also to all subgrids? I assume I need to do something regarding the `postData`, but I am still new to jqGrid.

I know I could add the filter toolbar to the subgrids, but that is not an acceptable solution from a UX perspective. The user should be able to search all fields for the main grid and all subgrids from the single (main) filter toolbar.

The colModel property of the main grid and the subgrids are the same and is displayed below.

```js
var mainGridPrefix = "s_";

colModel: [
      { name: 'active', index: 'active' }
    , { name: 'lastContact', index: 'lastContact', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: "m/d/Y" } }
    , { name: 'nextContact', index: 'nextContact', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: "m/d/Y" } }
]
, idPrefix: mainGridPrefix
, subGrid: true
, subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
    var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
        pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, rowId),
        colModel = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");

    $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
    $subgrid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local"
        , data: $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", pureRowId).subgridData
        , colModel: [
      { name: 'active', index: 'active' }
    , { name: 'lastContact', index: 'lastContact', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: "m/d/Y" } }
    , { name: 'nextContact', index: 'nextContact', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: "m/d/Y" } }
        ]
        , height: "100%"
        , rowNum: 10000
        , autoencode: true
        , gridview: true
        , idPrefix: rowId + "_"
        , width: $("#tableId").width() - 25
    });
    $subgrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view").children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv").hide();
}
```

Comment: You posted only `colModel` without more details. It's not full clear what you do. For example you write about "subgrids". Do you use ["Subgrid as Grid"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) (uses `subGridRowExpanded` callback) or you use legacy subgrids (`subGridModel`)? Do you use `idPrefix`? How you fill the data in subgrids? Which `datatype` you use for the main grid and for subgrids?

Comment: Moreover you posted `colModel` with a lot of unneeded pproperties. For example `{ name: 'active', index: 'active', sorttype: 'text', align: 'left' }` is the same as `{ name: 'active' }`. It's better to remove unneeded properties and to use templates to make the code shorter and better to read and maintain. I recommend to use column template too. In the simplest way you can define `var myDate = {sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: "m/d/Y" }}` and to use `{ name: 'lastContact', template: myDate }` and `{ name: 'nextContact', template: myDate }`

Comment: @Oleg I have edited the above question to include the information you requested.

Comment: I still not full understand what scenario you want to implement. The subgrids exist only if the user expends the subgrid. Let us the main grid has the filter toolbar and the user fills some text in some fields and press `<ENTER>`. What information should be shown? Do you want that the subgrids, which will be opened later, just uses **the same** `postData.filters` like it's in the main grid? Do you want reopen all previously opened subgrids applying the filter?

Comment: @Oleg After the user enters some information in the fields and presses `<ENTER>` then it should show all rows from the main grid **and all subgrids** that match the specified criteria. It would be beneficial if it automatically opened the subgrids to display, but that is not a requirement. If piggybacking the subgrids to use the main grid's `postData.filters` is an option, then that will likely work if I understand it correctly.

Comment: I have no ideas about the data in the grid. The subgrid can match to the filter entered by the user, but the parent row not match. What should be displayed in the case? One can't display subgrid without to display the parent grid? In general I'm not sure that subgrid is good model for your data. Why all subtrids contains the same columns like the main grid? All TreeGrid for example contains the same columns. Is it not better for you?

Comment: In general if you need to apply the filter in the way which you described then you can just get `postData.filters` and `search` of the main grid inside of `subGridRowExpanded` and to use the same values. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm) or [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-bootstrap.htm), which apply the filter. You can do the same in your subgrids. What you need to do is just opening of all subgrids. You can hide all empty subgrids in the same way line you hide the column headers.

Comment: @Oleg thank you for that suggestion! I have went that route, but unfortunately am now facing a different issue. =/ I have made a new question regarding that. [New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399912/free-jqgrid-treegrid-filter-not-working)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure that you understood me correctly. I don't understand what kind of data you try to display. I find suspected, the the main grid and the subgrids contains the same columns. I recommended you to consider in which form to display the data. Together with TreeGrid there are exist data grouping, which looks close to TreeGrid and subgrids.  I have no idea about the nature of the data and thus I don't know which form is the best for your data. TreeGrid was just an example and nothing more.

Comment: You wrote that you need some kind of filtering of *the whole data*. I don't understand whether the parent element should be display after filtering or not. It can be that that you need just use one flat grid without subgrids, TreeGrid or data grouping. It more corresponds the requirement of filtering. I want to repeat, that I posted no answer and gives you no clear recommendation because I still don't understand the nature of your data, the best form of displaing the data and the logic of filtering of the data.

Comment: Your recommendation of TreeGrid is exactly what I needed. The data in the grid is 100% related. The main (parent) records are companies, and the sub (children) records are employees at said company. As I mentioned above, I went the TreeGrid route and it is exactly what I need but the top filtering toolbar is no longer working.

Comment: If the parent record is the company of the employees of the company, then the model of data could be data grouping too. One can group the employees by company. The summary row is the information about the company. jqGrid allows to specify `groupSummaryPos: "header"`. It creates the grid with "parent" row with probably the same information and very close look as you have now. The main difference: the summary header is **not part of the data** and you will able to filter *the data* and then display the results as grouped grid.

Comment: [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/grouping2-summaryTypeAsArray.htm) and [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/grouping2-summaryTypeAsArray2_.htm) are examples of usage data grouping and displaying summary information in the headers (with some advanced features). The look of the grid is close to TreeGrid, but it's not the same. "Parent nodes" are not the part of the data. Thus the filtering problem can be solved in natural way using the approach. See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/grouping2-summaryTypeAsArray-filter.htm)